# How to show that the series of functions $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k + 1}}{2k + 1}$ is pointwise convergent to a function?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, pointwise-convergence

The problem I'm given is as follows:

> Consider the sequence of functions $(f_k)_k$, where $f_k(x) = (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k + 1}}{2k + 1}$ as well as the resulting series: $$A(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty f_k (x)$$
> Show that the series converges *pointwise* towards a function $f(x)$ for all $x \in (-1, 1)$. It is not yet necessary to show which $f$ the series converges to.

My confusion in answering this question arises from the fact that the tests (Cauchy and M-Test) determine **uniform convergence**, which is stronger than pointwise. I understand that passing either test would be necessary and sufficient for uniform convergence and therefore also for pointwise, but since the question asks only to show pointwise convergence, I'm a bit lost.

My approach is as follows:

1. By the ratio test, I have shown that the series converges absolutely (to a value) for all $x \in (-1, 1)$.
2. The next step should be to somehow justify that the values for each $x$ that the series converges to belong to a function, but I am not sure how to do that.

If anyone could help me to structure the last step, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: you can fix $x_0$ and then study the numerical series $\sum f_k(x_0)$

Comment: Probably here the usage of Cauchy-Hadamard theorem is mentioned?

Comment: are you familiar with the tools of power series?

Comment: @SineoftheTime could you please elaborate on that approach? Power series were very loosely introduced, so not really.

Comment: @EgorIvanov nope :(

Comment: using theorems related to power series, you can find the radius of convergence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the series $\sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ converges for $|x|<1$ and that it converges to $\arctan x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132396/show-that-the-series-sum-k-0-infty-1k-fracx2k12k1-converges) (look at the beginning of the accepted answer) alternatively, $\left|(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k + 1}}{2k + 1}\right|\le|x|^{2k + 1}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty|x^{2k+1}|=\frac{|x|}{1-x^2}<\infty$ hence your series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @AnneBauval It's a start... we haven't been introduced to what a radius of convergence is and I was looking for an answer with more explanation

Comment: In my alternative solution in the previous comment, I did not use the radius of convergence, not even the ratio test. Sorry, I could have edited my solution as an answer but now the post is closed.

Comment: I understand the use of the ratio test, what I'm not grasping is the relation between absolute and pointwise convergence

Comment: @PriyamTurakhia if you can't use power series and you want to use the most basic tools, just fix $x_0$ and study the behaviour of $\sum f_k(x_0)$

Comment: @AnneBauval it's OK, I reckon I can piece something together with the other post

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence It is much more fundamental than the alternating series test. Absolute convergence of a series of complex *numbers* (not functions) famously implies ordinary convergence. Both are "pointwise" in your context, i.e. for $x$ fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we really have to constraint ourselves to the minimal level of math knowledge needed. Since you mentioned no integral, I assume no Taylor series either, so there is no way for you to tell what $f(x)$ is, but you do not seem to need that.

The most direct way is the [ratio test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/RatioTest.aspx), which proves the absolute convergence of the series. May be this suffice?

Comment: But how do absolute and pointwise convergence relate?

Comment: @PriyamTurakhia if the function's value absolutely converges (as a series) at each $x$, then the function pointwise converges.