# Is my proof that $\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1}$ correct?

Tags: power-series

Respected All

I was trying to prove that 
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
What I tried to show like this.

We know 
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=(1+x^2)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nx^{2n}, |x^2|<1$$
Integrating term by term with in interval of convergence we get 
$$\int_0^{x_0}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{x_0^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
Taking $x_0=1$ we have 
$$[\arctan(x)]_0^1=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1}$$
i.e. $$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1}$$

Am I right?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Also, you can directly use Maclaurin series of $\arctan(x)$ to conclude. [This](http://prntscr.com/6urfzz) is the series I'm talking about.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, Anjan There is one missing step. You can't just plug in $x_0=1$ because convergence is only on the interior of the unit disk. Instead, you should note that it converges as it is an alternating series, and use Abel's theorem to show that it equals $\arctan(1)$.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, due to the extra step I mentioned; please reopen this so I can finish my answer.

Comment: I tried but it requires 3 more votes :-(

Comment: @AnjanDebnath Yeah, it will take some time. The note was so that people in the reopen queue know why I nominated.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It has been reopened now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already 90% of the way there; using term-by-term integration or any of the other methods described at [Taylor series of $\arctan$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29649/50776), you can derive

$$\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1},\qquad |x|<1,$$

but you cannot claim directly that this is true for $x=1$ because this is out of the range of the equation. (You can't do term-by-term integration on the interval $[0,1]$ because the $\sum\int=\int\sum$ theorem is only valid when convergence is uniform, and *a priori* you only know that the power series is uniformly convergent on $[0,x]$ for any $|x|<1$.)

But with a little extra work, we can push this equality out to the boundary of the unit circle, using [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). This says that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series then $$\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n.$$

And we know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ is convergent, because it is an alternating series. Thus $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\arctan x$$ (because the power series is valid for $|x|<1$), and this is equal to $\arctan 1=\frac{\pi}4$ because arctan is continuous in a neighborhood of $1$ (indeed, in a neighborhood of $\Bbb R$).

By the way, just yesterday I submitted a formal proof of this exact theorem in [Metamath](http://us2.metamath.org:88/mpegif/leibpisum.html), so I got to see all the little complications that are glossed over in this exposition.

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side

$$S=-i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{i^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

$$2iS=\ln\dfrac{1+i}{1-i}=\ln\dfrac{(1+i)^2}2=\ln(i)$$

using $\ln(1+x)$ expansion

As $i=e^{i\pi/2},$  the principal value of $\ln(i)=\dfrac{i\pi}2$

Comment: Its been a long time :-)