# Sum of alternate series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have found an exercise in an exam; however, I don't know where to start. 
Find the sum of the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)} $$

I just learned how to do it with polynomials in the numerator.

Comment: Do you know about Taylor series?

Comment: for arctan, in particular?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238780/is-my-proof-that-frac-pi4-sum-limits-n-geq-0-1n-frac12n1-corr.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{2n+1}$$ which converges in $[-1,1)$. It reminds of a geometric series, but there are those annoying denominators.

From there, consider

$$xf(-x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1},$$ where the exponents are the same as the denominators. You can differentiate term-wise to get a true geometric series, that you can sum:

$$(xf(-x^2))'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}=\frac 1{1+x^2}.$$

Now integrating from $0$ to $1$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n1^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\arctan 1.$$