# Problem related to Inverse Trigonometry of Complex Numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, inverse

$\large{\begin{cases} P = \dfrac{\tan^{-1}(\alpha)}{\alpha} + \dfrac{\tan^{-1}(\beta)}{\beta} + \dfrac{\tan^{-1}(\gamma)}{\gamma} \\ \text{ . } \\ \text{ . } \\ Q = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{6n+1} \end{cases} }$

If $\alpha, \ \beta, \ \gamma  $ are the three cube roots of unity, submit the value of $\dfrac{P}{Q}$ as your answer.

This was the question I came across today.I know most of the properties of cube roots of unity.But how to handle the arctangents of complex numbers?I never saw such an expression.Any suggestions?

My knowledge of maths is upto high school.So please give your answer accordingly.Thanks.

Comment: All your questions seem to be got from brilliant.org, the purpose of question is to answer them without "cheating"

Comment: @OussamaBoussif I have no interest in answering the questions on brilliant.org...I simply use it for self practise.You might even see my profile there...i hardly answer any questions there to increase my reputation...that can't be called "cheating" because i dont answer questions there.

Comment: That was just on observation I made. But in future questions at least show what you tried, I am sure that you'll be able to solve this one.

Comment: I can calculate Q @OussamaBoussif but not sure about P.....because that involves arctan(w) and arctanc(w^2)....I dont know how to handle that...

Comment: You don't need to know anything about inverse trig functions of complex numbers.  You do need to know about the Taylor expansion of the arctan, and once you write that down, the answer should be clear.

Comment: but is taylor series valid for complex numbers @RonGordon ? I thought of that once..

Comment: They are valid for all numbers of magnitude less than or equal to one.  Find a proof of that if you need, but that is the case.

Comment: @RonGordon thanks for that...got the proof here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots

Comment: @OussamaBoussif how did you get that formula :O!!!Please let me know!Taylor series?Or some other method?

Comment: Just use the fact that $\arctan{x}=\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$ and that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-ix}+\frac{1}{1+ix})$

Comment: @OussamaBoussif nice one...:)...good to learn something new!thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. But do you know how to handle the logarithm of complex numbers?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif like $ln z=ln|z|+i arg(z)$ ?

Comment: Ah in that case you know it. Now apply the identity and see what you can get from it

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake in that identity here's the correct one: $\arctan{x}=\frac{1}{2i}\ln{\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}}$

Comment: @OussamaBoussif got the answer using taylor series..its coming 1...now trying your method