# Coincidence that series of arctan is alternating series of artanh?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, trigonometric-series

I noticed that the power series for $\arctan$ is the alternating series of that for $\operatorname{arctanh}$.

Does it have a special meaning or even some kind of special importance?

Comment: You should try to make the body of the Question as self-contained as possible, not relying on the title alone to carry the burden of stating the problem.  Mathematical expressions can be posted here using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ markup.

Comment: The relations between trigonometric and hyperbolic functions are well-known. See [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).

Answer (score 5):

The hyperbolic and trigonometric functions are real/imaginary counterparts of each other.

$$\arctan(ix)=i\,\text{artanh}(x),\\
\text{artanh}(ix)=i\,\arctan(x).$$

For an odd series,

$$\sum_k a_k(ix)^{2k+1}=i\sum_k a_k(-1)^kx^{2k+1}.$$

So yes, there is a fundamental relation.

Comment: It should apply to more than just arctan and arctanh, i.e., all trig functions and hyperbolic functions related by imaginary transformations of the arguments. Incomplete list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Hyperbolic_functions_for_complex_numbers

Comment: @NoviceC: it applies to all odd or even power series. And you let an ordinary series alternate just by changing the sign of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

An other way to see that is to recall that one easily know that

$$ \arctan'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n(x^2)^n, $$

and

$$ \text{artanh}'(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (x^2)^n. $$

Integrating these series (for more details, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots)) and using that $\arctan(0)=\text{artanh}(0)$, it explains the alternated signs.