# series of $\tan^{-1}(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two questions about the series of $$\tan^{-1}(x)$$ for $\lvert x\rvert >1$:
How can we  derive the 2 following series?
$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{3x^3}-\ldots$$ for $x>1$.
$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{-\pi}{2} -\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{3x^3}-\ldots$$ for $x<-1$. 
I found a solution that integrate $$\frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} $$ from $ -\infty$ to $x$ to get the first series and from $x$ to $\infty$ to get the second series.
Can I integrate $$\frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} $$ indefinitely then to get the constant value, I substitute by $x=\infty$ and $ x=-\infty$ so we get two different values for the constant hence we have two different series? Is this correct mathematically?

---

Second,
I want to understand how can I relate $$\frac{-\pi}{2}$$ and $$\frac{-\pi}{2}$$  (which is the constant in the series) to the quadrant of the angle ..?
So I put the first series in this form
 $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta\right)=x$$
and I put the second series in this form
 $$\tan\left(\frac{-\pi}{2}+\theta\right)=x$$
where $$\theta=-\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{3x^3}-...$$ 
But I don't know how to complete thinking?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots.  This will help you

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple: use the relation
$$\arctan x+\arctan \frac1x=\frac\pi2\qquad \text{for all}\enspace x>0,$$
the Taylor series for $\arctan u$, which converges for all $\lvert u\rvert<1$ and set $u=\dfrac1x$.