# Evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n-1}) $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation

Prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n-1})=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Could someone give me slight hint as how to convert above expression to $\int_{0}^{1} \tan^{-1}x.dx$

Comment: its telescoping..

Comment: @ILoveMath, Is it? Can we use  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your series comes out to be
$$1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{11}+\cdots$$
This can be written as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$
and is the well known [Leibniz formula for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80). Note that your series is on the hyperlinked Wikipedia page under the section "Convergence". The easiest way to show that this is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is to show that the $\arctan$ function has a Taylor Series
$$\arctan(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} + \cdots$$
Now plug in $x=1$. The Taylor Series is valid here: the interval of convergence is $[-1,1]$

If you want a more complete proof the Wikipedia link should suffice, or see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_Formula_for_Pi). For another proof of the Taylor Series formula see [the Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots) linked in the comments by @lab_bhattacharjee

Answer (score 0):

By IBP,
\begin{eqnarray*}\int \tan^{-1}x.dx&=&x\times tan^{-1}x|-\int x\times \frac{1}{1+x^2}.dx \\
&=&x\times tan^{-1}x|-\int \frac{d(x^2+1)}{2dx}\times \frac{1}{1+x^2}.dx\\
&=&x\times tan^{-1}x|-\ln|x^2+1| |
  \end{eqnarray*}