# Is this a valid representation of pi?

Tags: notation, pi

Is this a valid representation of pi ?

---

$$ \pi = \sum_{x=1}^\infty   \left(\frac{4}{4x-3} - \frac{4}{4x-1}\right)$$

Comment: Set $x=1$ in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots

Comment: This is so called Leibniz series.

Comment: $$\pi = 4\arctan(1)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) It's just $$  \sum_{x=1}^\infty   \left(\frac{4}{4x-3} - \frac{4}{4x-1}\right)=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}=\pi$$

Comment: @Thomas $x$ is the summation variable.