# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)3^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)3^n}.$$

-A solution related to converting it into power series and then applying integration will be appreciated! I cant seem to express it as a power series.

[The question in the book- picture, click!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNqxk.jpg)

Comment: After some manipulation, it reduces to $-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n }{n}$ (antiderivative of the geometric series)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider the power series expansion of $\arctan(x)$ at $0$: for $x\in(-1,1]$
$$\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}=x+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(x^2)^n}{(2n+1)}.$$
See [Why is $\arctan(x)=x-x^3/3+x^5/5-x^7/7+\dots$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots)