# How is $\int_0^x\sum_{k=0}^n(-t^2)^k+\frac{(-t^2)^{n+1}}{1+t^2}dt$ derived

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Could someone please explain, in an answer to a [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots), how is

$$\int_0^x\sum_{k=0}^n(-t^2)^k+\frac{(-t^2)^{n+1}}{1+t^2}dt$$

derived from $$\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subsitute $x$ in $\sum_{k=0}^nx^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ as $-t^2$.

More detail :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-t^2)^k+\frac{(-t^2)^{n+1}}{1+t^2}=\frac{1-(-t^2)^{n+1}}{1+t^2}+\frac{(-t^2)^{n+1}}{1+t^2}=\frac{1}{1+t^2}.$$ I don't think it can be more explicit..

Comment: yes, that's what i did initially, but i don't get it..Could you please expand?

Comment: yes, now i see that it was obvious. Thanks for clearing it up for me!