# Prove that $\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$ for $x \to +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Want to prove that $$\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \ \text{as}~~~  x \to +\infty$$

Wolfram says that it's true but I'm trying to find some formal prove of this equality.

Here's what i found about that:

We know that $\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_x^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1 + t^2}$ (we can easily prove this by solving such integral). But what this one can give us for asymptotic assessment?

Seems like we have to prove that this integral equals to $-\frac{1}{x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$, but how?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-is-arctanx-x-x3-3x5-5-x7-7-dots) help?

Comment: *Hint*: $\arctan(x)=\frac\pi2-\arctan(1/x)$ for $x>0$ and you know $\arctan(t)\approx t$ for $\lvert t\rvert\ll 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $$\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \ \text{as}~~~  x \to +\infty,$$
you have to prove (by definition)
$$\limsup_{ x\to +\infty}\left|\frac{\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^3}}\right|<\infty.
$$
This can be easily done by calculating $\lim_{ x\to +\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^3}}$ using L'Hôpital's rule. As you want to use $\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_x^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1 + t^2}$, you get
$$\lim_{ x\to +\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^3}}=\lim_{ x\to +\infty}\frac{- \int_x^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1 + t^2} + \frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^3}} =\lim_{ x\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1 + x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}}{-\frac{3}{x^4}}=\lim_{ x\to +\infty}\frac{1}{3}\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: As you wrote, $\arctan x = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \int_x^\infty\dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}.$ And that can be written as

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2} + \int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2} - \int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}.$$

Comment: Seems like here we only have to prove that $\int_x^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^2(1 + t^2)} = O(\frac{1}{x^3})$. In what way I have to think to prove it?

Comment: That integral is smaller than $\int_x^\infty 1/t^4\,dt=1/(3t^3).$

Comment: Oops, the last term should be $1/(3x^3).$