# Deriving closed formulas for summations

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value of $\\sum x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-xn)

I was wondering how to derive a closed formula for things like $\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{n}$=$2(2^{n}-1)$ and $\sum_{n=k}^{n}2^{n-k}$=$2^{n-k+1}-1$. I haven't done this in a while, and had wolfram do it for me, and I am not sure what the general tactic in getting these formulas is. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Look up "geometric series".

Comment: But there the other two ways are not mentioned; thought they are essentially the same.

Comment: I am still not clear on how to get something that starts not with 0 but with n-k for example, as in my example.

Comment: If you're seeking tricks and heuristics see Graham; Knuth; Patashnik: *Concrete Mathematics*. If you're seeking algorithms see Carsten Schneider's thesis [Symbolic summation in Difference Fields](http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_3017/SymbSumTHESIS.pdf), 2001, and Petkovsek; Wilf; Zeilberger: [A = B.](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can consider three ways, for one, use the inductive method; for two, try to write down what you want to sum, and then multiply it by 2 and subtract them; for three, try to write it as a recurrence relation, and compute it as usual. In each case, just remember that x-1 is a divisor of $x^n -1$ when n is a strictly positive natural number.