# Geometric series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value of $\sum x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-xn)

Hello,
there is a sequence described by:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(Ax)^i$$
there is also written that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(Ax)^i = \frac{Ax}{1-Ax}$$
Question is, why the right side is equal to the left side? I thought about calculation of limit of left side and like for me it should be:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(Ax)^i \text{goes to } \infty$$