# Is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n$ equal to $-1$? Why?

Tags: power-series, fake-proofs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Divisibility with sums going to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73520/divisibility-with-sums-going-to-infinity)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and [Minute Physics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIq5CZlg8Rg) i see that the sum would be -1. I find this challenging to understand, how does a sum of positive integers end up being negative?

Comment: It's true in the $2$-adic integers.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023) as well.

Comment: Say you found a norm on $\mathbb{Z}$ where |2|<1. Then $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^n = \frac{1}{1 - 2} = -1.$ Such a norm exists, it's called the $2$-adic norm. In fact, it is the unique norm on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|2| < 1.$

Comment: I miss the points about the 2-adic norms and analytic continuations on the other question!

Comment: Related : [Divergent series and p-adics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141971/divergent-series-and-p-adics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only does so *formally*, not literally according to the usual definition of infinite series convergence over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. The idea is to take the series to mean the familiar geometric series and *analytically continue* it as a function to arguments where the original definition does not work. I attempted [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68746/general-question-on-relation-between-infinite-series-and-complex-numbers/68779#68779) in another question as to what [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) entails exactly. One may also use a variety of [summability methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Summability_methods) to evaluate these sums, whereby we alter or redefine the partial sums in some way in order to get a finite answer. The motivation for these perhaps seemingly artificial practices is that they are examples of [regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics)) and [renormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) of expressions naturally occuring in modern physics containing divergent or infinite factors.

Suggestively, it does actually hold in a *literal* sense over [$2$-adic integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number). The fact that the series converges 2-adically follows from $|2^n|_2=2^{-n}\to0$, and if we wanted to have fun we could pull an Euleresque stunt and call the sum $S$, multiply by $2$ and say $2S=S-1\implies S=-1$.

Answer (score 4):

It's all about the principle of analytic continuation.  The function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ defines an analytic function in the unit disk, equal to the meromorphic function $g(z)=1/(1-z)$.  Note that the equality $f\equiv g$ holds *only* in the disk, where $f$ converges absolutely.  Despite this, if we naively wanted to assign *any* value to $f(x)$ outside of $\vert z \vert < 1$, an intuitive choice would be to set $f(2)=g(2)= -1$.  Moreover, the theory of complex functions implies that this is somehow the *only* possible choice (for this function, at least).

The principle is called [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation), and it is incredibly important in many areas of mathematics, most notably complex analysis.