# How to evaluate series. eg. $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn)

In my lecture notes:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}, \qquad \sum_{n-1}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2^n}) = 1$$

How do I get $(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$?

A similar example given is

$$a_n = 2^{n-1}, \qquad \sum_{n-1}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (2^n - 1)$$

How do I get these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are from the standard formula for the sum of a finite geometric series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^nar^k=\frac{a-ar^{n+1}}{1-r}=\frac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1}\;.\tag{1}$$

Write $$S=\sum_{k=0}^nar^k\;;$$ then

$$\begin{align*}S&=a\color{red}{+ar+ar^2+\dots+ar^{n-1}+ar^n}\\
rS&=\quad\;\;\,\color{red}{ar+ar^2+\dots+ar^{n-1}+ar^n}+ar^{n+1}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and when you subtract the second equation from the first, the red terms cancel out to leave $(1-r)S=a+ar^{n+1}$, from which $(1)$ follows immediately.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}, \qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2^n}) = 1$$

Depends how you interpret it.  First let us look at the solution to

First we will be using (for  $r<1$)

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} ar^{k} = \frac{a- ar^{n+1}}{1-r}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}
$$

Now in the problem above

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$$  and therefore

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\\
&= {\frac{1}{2}} ( 1 + \frac{1}{2^{1}} + \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \dots )\\
&= {\frac{1}{2}} (\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}})
&= 1
\end{align*}
$$

And

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2^n}) = 1 - \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

It is just a way to rewrite the series which is also explained on the relevant [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence).

Basically all you have to know is that

$$(1+r+r^2+r^3+\ldots+r^n)(1-r)=1-r^{n+1}$$