# Prove Algebric Identity

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn)

Given $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<a<1$

let $(X_n)$ be a sequence defined: $X_n=1+a+a^2+...+a^n$,  $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

How do I show that $X_n=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is given in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29024/2468

Answer (score 1):

Note $aX_n = a + a^2 + \dots + a^n + a^{n+1}$, so that 
$$X_n - aX_n = 1 - a^{n+1},$$ and then you can probably figure it out from there...

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
(1-a)(1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n)&=(1+a+\dots+a^n)-a(1+a++\dots+a^n)\\
&=(1+\color{red}{a+\dots+a^n})-(\color{red}{a+a^2++\dots+a^n}+a^{n+1})\\
&=1-a^{n+1}
\end{align*}$$