# Geometric Series Converges?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, power-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn)

If I have some real $x$ where $0 < x < 1$

What is the value $y = x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \dots$ ?

Intuitively I can see that for $x = 0.5$ then $y = 1$

How do I calculate this for arbitrary $x$?

Comment: This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: What you've written, $0>x>1$, makes no sense. Presumably you mean to write $0<x<1$?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell: It makes perfect sense, it's just always false. :)  I've corrected the type, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You mean $0<x<1$.)

This is just a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with first term and ratio $x$, so $$y=\frac{x}{1-x}\;.$$

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know much about series maybe the following is helpful.

Suppose that such a sum exists. It is clear that $y=x+x(x+x+x^2+\cdots)=x+xy.$ Just find $y$ from the equation $y=x+xy.$ (I'm neglecting some limits here).

Answer (score 1):

Do not memorize the formula. You can derive it using the following trick. Let $s=x+x^2+x^3+...$. Then you have that $sx=x^2+x^3+x^4+...$. Hence, $s-sx=x$. In other words, $s=\frac{x}{1-x}$

Comment: Some find remembering the formula superior to re-deriving it every time.  Others not.

Comment: Actually my series was $y = 6x - 2x^2 + 6x^3 - 2x^2 + 6x^5 + ...$, so the derivation helped much more than the formulae