# Geometric sequences; partial sums with sum notation going from n=1 to infinity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn)

I have been working on this problem for awhile and have made efforts to try to resolve it. The question is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 7(0.1)^{n−1}$$

Comment: thank you for responding, but i was asking if anyone knows how to find the partial sum of this expression.

Comment: I don't see any question, but a formula!

Answer (score 0):

For the "partial sum", I assume you meant
$\sum_{n=1}^k 7(0.1)^{n−1}$ for any positive integer $k$.

Taking the $7$ out of the sum, and shifting the exponent,
we get
$7\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} 0.1^n$.

All this needs now is the standard formula
$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} x^n = (x^k-1)/(x-1) = (1-x^k)/(1-x)$.
Putting $x = 0.1$, 
$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} 0.1^n = (1-0.1^k)/0.9$.