# Closed form formula for the following sum

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Does anyone know of a closed-form formula for the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty x^{2^n-1}$? We can assume that $0<x<1$.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating the sum of geometric series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283159/evaluating-the-sum-of-geometric-series)

Comment: @Amr, no, this is not a duplicate of that. This has $x^{2^n}$, not $x^n$ like a geometric series.

Comment: I think I saw a question extremely similar to this on this site (the exponent was $2^n$ instead of $2^n - 1$). The general consensus was that it is unlikely there is a closed form.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams OH. I thought that it had $x^{2n-1}$ and not $x^{2^n-1}$

Comment: For most $x$ (especially those much smaller than $1$) you can approximate that to very good accuracy because the tail is so small.

Comment: This question is very similar to: [Power Series Formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276892/power-series-summation-formula). However, this question should NOT be closed because it asks for an infinite sum, whereas the other one requests a partial sum.

Comment: This is known as a [lacunary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).  I do not know much about them, but I understand they can exhibit very complicated behavior, so I would not expect a simple formula to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Further discussion of this topic is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276892/power-series-summation-formula) (except that topic refers to partial sums). However, I did give an estimate [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282039/54806), which gives:

$$ -\frac{\mathrm{Ei}\left(\log (x)\right)}{x\log (2)} \le \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{2^i - 1} \le -\frac{\mathrm{Ei}\left(\frac{\log (x)}{2}\right)}{x\log (2)}  $$

Where $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ is the [Exponential Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

Comment: Hmm... Seems like there's no hope :) 
Approximations are good, but not for what I want to do. Appreciate the comment though!