# What is the formula of: $a^{0} + a^{1} + a^{2} + ... + a^{n-1} + a^{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, closed-form

What is the formula of:

$$a^{0} + a^{1} + a^{2} + ... +  a^{n-1} + a^{n}$$

Any ideas?

Comment: See the question [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29023/752), in particular [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29035/752) answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For $a=1$ this is simple. Otherwise, what happens when you multiply it by $a-1$?

Comment: +1. What happens? We watch the dominoes falling...

Answer (score 2):

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

it is called a gemoetric series and it is a standard result.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1,a^{0} + a^{1} + a^{2} + ... +  a^{n-1} + a^{n}=1+1+\cdots$ up to $(n+1)$  terms hence $=n+1$

Else let $S=a^{0} + a^{1} + a^{2} + ... +  a^{n-1} + a^{n}$

So, $a\cdot S=a^{1} + a^{2} + a^{3} + ... +  a^{n} + a^{n+1}$

So, $S(a-1)=a^{n+1}-1$

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{n}-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+\cdots+1)\implies a^{n-1}+\cdots+1=\dfrac{a^{n}-1}{a-1}$$ where $a \neq 1$

Comment: Check your algebra.

Comment: @leo: Thanks. I didn't notice that.