# General formula of partial sum of series (non-geometric)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Like user71317 in his [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400792/general-formula-for-partial-sum-of-series) I am struggling to understand how we arrive at the general formula of the partial sums of a series. In my case the following series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1}$$

The general formula of the partial sums is:

$$s_n=\sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2-1} = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

I understand the answer to the linked question where the answer *is the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series*. Since my series is not geometric; how do I go from the series to the partial sums in this case?

**Update:**

How is $\sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2-1}$ equal to $\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my original question. I don't fully understand how $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1}$ is equal to $\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$?

Comment: It makes no sense to say that $$\frac1{2^2-1}+\frac1{3^2-1}+\frac1{4^2-1}+\dots=\frac{3}{4}-\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2(n+1)}.$$ Perhaps you mean to ask for a proof that $$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac1{n^2-1}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac1{2N}-\frac{1}{2(N+1)}?$$

Comment: I have updated my question again. This time hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now. A proof is on ts way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find $$f(N)=\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac1{n^2-1}$$
then you should note that $$\frac1{n^2-1}=\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac12\cdot\frac1{n+1}$$
so 
$$\begin{align}
f(N)&=\frac12\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac1{n-1}-\frac12\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n+1}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{n}-\frac12\sum_{n=3}^{N+1}\frac1n\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{n}-\frac12\left[-1-\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac1n\right]\\
&=\frac34+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{n}-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac1n\ .
\end{align}$$
Then recall that 
$$H_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac1i=\int_0^1\frac{t^k-1}{t-1}dt\ .$$
So we have that 
$$\begin{align}
f(N)&=\frac34+\frac12 H_{N-1}-\frac12H_{N+1}\\
&=\frac34+\frac12 \int_0^1\frac{(t^{N-1}-1)-(t^{N+1}-1)}{t-1}dt\\
&=\frac34-\frac12 \int_0^1\frac{t^{N+1}-t^{N-1}}{t-1}dt\\
&=\frac34-\frac12 \int_0^1t^{N-1}\frac{t^2-1}{t-1}dt\\
&=\frac34-\frac12 \int_0^1t^{N-1}\frac{(t-1)(t+1)}{t-1}dt\\
&=\frac34-\frac12 \int_0^1t^{N-1}(t+1)dt\\
&=\frac34-\frac12 \int_0^1t^N dt-\frac12\int_0^1 t^{N-1}dt\\
&=\frac34-\frac1{2(N+1)}-\frac1{2N}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: You don't actually need the integrals in the last set of equations,  since we know $H_{n+1} = H_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yeah, I know, but I just thought it would be a little more fun to use the integrals.

Comment: Telescoping sums...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1})$

Answer (score 0):

This series can be converted into a telescoping series. Using partial fraction decomposition, we can see that
$$\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
2\sum_{r=2}^n\frac{1}{r^2-1}&=\sum_{r=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{r-1}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}\\
&~+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\\
&~+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\\
&~~~~~~~\vdots~~~~~~~\vdots\\
&~+\frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n}\\
&~+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\\
\end{align}$$
And all the terms will cancel apart from $4$ of them, so we are left with
$$2\sum_{r=2}^n\frac{1}{r^2-1}=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
which means that $$\sum_{r=2}^n\frac{1}{r^2-1}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

---

We can take the limit as $n\to\infty$ to find that
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r^2-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2-1}=\frac{3}{4}$$