# Irreducible quadratic "within" reducible quadratic

Tags: quadratics, irreducible-polynomials

If we have a *reducible* quadratic function

\begin{equation*}
P(x)=a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=(rx-x_1)(tx-x_2),~x_1,x_2,r,t\in\mathbb{Z}, 
\end{equation*}

does there exist another *irreducible* quadratic function $Q(x)=a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2$ such that for every natural $x$, there exists a natural $y$ such that $Q(x)=P(y)$? For example, is there an irreducible quadratic function $Q(x)$ such that whenever $x\in\mathbb{N}$, $Q(x)$ is equal to

\begin{equation*}
P(y)=y^2-1=(y+1)(y-1) 
\end{equation*}

for some $y\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @GeorgeS Please don't edit questions to enforce a particular LaTeX style; for instance, don't edit `$$` into `\begin{equation*}` (e.g. in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29023/) and others).  These are trivial edits and bump posts unnecessarily.

Comment: @apnorton In George S's defense, it was previously \$ rather than \$\$, and he may simply think it is more readable this way.

Comment: yes, but the prior text was written so inline text made sense.  Rewording and re-TeX-ing simply to move `$` -> `{equation*}` is unnecessary at best.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This does not answer the question that was asked --- see comments**

The answer is no if you restrict to real-valued quadratics (which presumably we can because all complex-valued quadratics are reducible...). You can convince yourself of this by drawing some pictures of quadratics.

Take for example the reducible $P(x)=x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$.

Now $P(2)=+3$ and $P(0)=-1$.

Now suppose we have an irreducible $Q(x)$ and $y_1,\,y_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Q(y_1)=P(2)=+3$ and $Q(y_2)=P(x_2)=-1$.

As all quadratics are continuous this implies that $Q$ has a root between $y_1$ and $y_2$ and hence by the Factor Theorem has a factor and is thus reducible.

Comment: But it doesn't imply that the root is rational; note that we defined "reducible" as factorable into the form $(rx-x_1)(tx-x_2)$ for _integers_ $r,t,x_1,x_2$.