# Calculate sum of $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{7^n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

I need help with this excersise, can't figure it out, thanks alot !

Comment: Is the edit right? Or should it be $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{3}{7} \right)^n $

Comment: See [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn) (and maybe also some of the questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29023)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{3}{7^n}=3\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^n$, which is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple infinite geometric series with common ratio (r) 1/7 and first term (a) 3/7.
The sum = a/(1-r)

Answer (score 0):

use the geometric series for $|x|<1$
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+.....=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
for your series
$$x+x^2+x^3+x^4+....=x(1+x+x^2+x^3+....)=x*\frac{1}{1-x}$$
use $x=1/7$
$$3*(1/7)*\frac{1}{1-1/7}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{7^n} =3\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{7^n} =3\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{1}{7}\right|^n$$
Since $\left|\frac17\right| \lt 1$, then
$$3\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{1}{7}\right|^n=3\left(\frac{\frac17}{1-\frac17}\right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac{1}{7-1}\right)=\frac{3}{6}=\frac12$$
Study [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series).