# Test convergence of the series and find its sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1-2i}{2+3i}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Test convergence of the series and find its sum: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1-2i}{2+3i}\right)^n$$

My try:

This is simplified to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-i-8}{13}\right)^n$$

Then how to proceed?

Comment: How about, for convergence, finding out whether $\lvert \frac{-(1+2i)}{2+3i}\rvert <1$? Then, for the sum... it's a geometric series.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One knows that, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$
|z|<1 \implies\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n \quad \text{is convergent}
$$ and in this case
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\frac1{1-z}.
$$ What is $\left|\dfrac{-1-2i}{2+3i} \right|$ ?

Comment: $\left|\dfrac{-1-2i}{2+3i} \right|=\sqrt{65}/13$ and sum of the series is $13/(i+2)$ right?

Comment: @MatheMagic I find that the given series is equal to $\dfrac{21}{34}-\dfrac{i}{34}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1-2i}{2+3i}\right)^n
$

Since
$\frac{-1-2i}{2+3i}
=\frac{-1-2i}{2+3i}\frac{2-3i}{2-3i}
=\frac{-8-i}{13}
$
and
$|\frac{-8-i}{13}|^2
=\frac{65}{169}
\lt 1
$,
the sum converges.

Applying the standard formula,
the sum is

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{-8-i}{13}}
&=\dfrac{13}{13+(8+i)}\\
&=\dfrac{13}{21+i}\\
&=\dfrac{13}{21+i}\dfrac{21-i}{21-i}\\
&=\dfrac{13(21-i)}{442}\\
&=\dfrac{21-i}{34}\\
\end{array}
$