# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1 - x) x^k$ = 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is the following equation in a text I am reading

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1 - x) x^k = 1.
$$

I would like to know where does the identitity come from.

Is it from some telescopic property, e.g.,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1 - x) x^k &=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1 - x) x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k - x^{k+1}\\
&= 
[(x^0 - x^1) + (x^1 - x^2)]
\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^k - x^{k+1}\\
&= 
[(x^0 - x^2)]
\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^k - x^{k+1}\\
&= 
1 - x^2
\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^k - x^{k+1},
\end{align}

which, in the limit $x \to \infty$, would render the sum 0?

---

As can be seen from @qbert's answer, this seems to be a particular case of [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn), where we want to calculate

$$(1-x)\sum_n x^n,$$

for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: Edited the question to remark that it seems to be very similar to this question indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the geometric series identity 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda^k=\frac{1}{1-\lambda}
$$
So,
$$
(1-\lambda)\sum_{k=0}^\infty x\lambda^k\\
=x\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda^k-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda^{k+1}\right)\\
=x\left(\frac{1}{1-\lambda}-\lambda \sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda^{k}\right)\\
=x\left(\frac{1}{1-\lambda}-\lambda \frac{1}{1-\lambda}\right)\\
=x\
$$
where we used linearity of summation a bunch.

Comment: curious about the  downvote?

Comment: yes, me too! wonder why

Answer (score 1):

You used telescoping in a wrong way.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(x^k-x^{k+1})=x^0-x^1+x^1-x^2+\cdots-x^{n+1}=1-x^{n+1},$$

so that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(x^k-x^{k+1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n(x^k-x^{k+1})=1$$ when $|x|<1.$

Comment: Thanks! Now I see I should have first obtained the formula for the finite sum and **then** take the limit.