# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm hoping to get an expert opinion on the summation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n$$
I've attempted to find a closed-form of this expression as follows.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n=S_n$$
$$S_n=-x+x^2+-x^3+x^4...$$
$$-xS_n=x^2+-x^3+x^4+-x^5...$$
$$S_n(1+x)=-x$$
$$S_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n=\frac{-x}{x+1}$$
I'm curious whether there is a more rigorous way to derive this (involving more complex maths), or maybe to contradict my answer.

Another interesting thing is that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x)^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
and when you plot both on a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qc9ppp04ld) both they seem like rotations on one another ... but I don't know what do you guys think. Your input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your answer is correct. A more rigorous way would involve, probably, convergence radius (your  solution is correct **only for** $\;|x|<1$) . Perhaps you may want to read about Taylor and Maclaurin series.

Comment: It's a *geometric series*.

Comment: Clarifying DonAntonio's comment a bit, it's easier if your term $S_N$ is just a sum up to $N$ instead of $\infty$. Then using an algebraic rearrangement comparable to yours, you'd find that $S_N(1+x)=(-x)(1-(-x)^N)$. The $(1-(-x)^N)$ term only disappears under suitable conditions for $x$.

Comment: Also, using the variable $n$ in the term $S_n$ is slightly bad notation since $n$ was already used as an index in the sum so it can't be made into a variable.

Comment: There is an incredibly detailed similar answer for this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n$ is equal to $\frac{x}{1-x}$, not $\frac{-1}{x-1}$.

Comment: And then you just substitute $-x$ for $x$ in that formula to get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n=\frac{-x}{x+1}$.

Comment: and $\dfrac{-x}{1-(-x)}=\dfrac{-x}{x+1}$ explains symmetry on the graph