# How do I calculate the following number series without calculator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponential-function

Could anyone please tell me if there's any formula or something similar to calculate the following series easily without using a calculator.

$$1.12+(1.12)^2+(1.12)^3+(1.12)^4+(1.12)^5+(1.12)^6+(1.12)^7+(1.12)^8+(1.12)^9$$

Comment: This is a [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: If you add dollar signs on each side of the expression, it becomes a mathematical formula

Comment: The formula you're looking for is the [geometric series partial sum](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/how-to-find-the-partial-sum-of-a-geometric-sequence/) formula. It's still not easy to calculate without a calculator but it is easier.

Comment: @lulu Thank you so much! All the exponents made me confused and I missed it.

Comment: Related post on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/values-of-sum-n-0-infty-xn-and-sum-n-0n-xn)

Comment: If you want to work out the actual value of the result, you’ll need to work out $(1.12)^{10}$. I’d do this with exponentiation by squaring, or do a binomial approximation to a couple of terms if that’s acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_{n}$  is a Geometrics series and $x=
\frac{s_{i+1}}{s_{i}}, i= 0,1,2,...,9$, then
$S_{9}=\frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\frac{1.12-(1.12)^{10} }{1-1.12}=16.5487351$

Comment: It's a finite sum

Comment: I think you're getting downvoted because OP's question is asking for a specific "finite n" answer rather than the infinite series limit.

Comment: I see the confusion, however, when the title calls for a "series", in my mind typically implying the limit of partial sums

Comment: Yes, you can choose n = 9

Answer (score 0):

A sum of form $\sum_{m=1}^n r^m = r+r^2+r^3+...+r^n$ can be found in the following way:

Let $S_n = \sum_{m=1}^n r^m$ be the $n$th partial sum. Note $rS_n = r^2+r^3+...r^{n+1}$. Then $rS_n -S_n = r^{n+1}+r^n+...+r^3+r^2-(r^n+r^{n-1}+...+r^2)-r=r^{n+1}-r$. So factoring the left side yields $S_n = \frac{r^{n+1}-r}{r-1}$. So in your example we'd have  $\sum_{m=1}^9 (1.12)^m = \frac{1.12^{10}-1.12}{1.12-1}=16.549$.Your best chance for calculating  $\frac{1.12^{10}-1.12}{1.12-1}$ without a calculator might be to use $1.12 = 1+\frac{3}{25} = \frac{28}{25}$ and expand to get a (big) rational number.