# Induction proof I'm having trouble with: $1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction, geometric-progressions

So I'm being asked to use induction to prove that for every $x\in\{a\ |\ a\in R, a\neq 1\}$ and for every $n\in N$

$$
1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$

I have no trouble proving it for $n=1$ :

$$
1+x = \frac{1-x^2}{1-x}
$$
Factor the polynomial:
$$
1+x = \frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{1-x}
$$
Divide by $(1-x)$
$$
1+x=1+x
$$

And there you have it. The trouble I'm running into is with the induction step. If we assume that our claim is true for $n=k$ then
$$
1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^k+x^{k+1} = \frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}
$$
Or in other words,
$$
\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x} + x^{k+1} = \frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}
$$

Can someone help with this? I'm having some trouble with the factoring and the book I'm studying from isn't very clear on how they proved the last equation is true.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried to reduce both terms of the LHS to the same denominator? $$\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x} + x^{k+1} = \frac{1-x^{k+1}+(1-x) x^{k+1}}{1-x}=\dots$$

Comment: Yeah I did... Sorry if this sounds a little ignorant but I don't really see how that helps me...

Comment: OK, I'll write a solution.

Comment: Oh wait... I think I got it... how could I not see that? I should distribute the x^(k+1) onto (1-x) and get a numerator of 1-x^(k+1)+x^(k+1)-x^(k+2)

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/proof-of-the-formula-1xx2x3-cdots-xn-fracxn1-1x-1) or [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563535/prove-that-1aa2-cdotsan-1-an1-1-a). (Or other questions from [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/11703) or maybe even [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29023)) You will find various proofs there, but certainly some answers will have induction proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you are stuck, there is only one little step left: reduce both terms of the LHS to the same denominator. That is, $$\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x} + x^{k+1} = \frac{1-x^{k+1}+(1-x) x^{k+1}}{1-x}=\frac{1-x^{k+1}+x^{k+1} - x\cdot x^{k+1}}{1-x} = \frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}.$$

Comment: I should have seen that. Been studying for six hours straight now so I must be tired and just missed it. Thanks a million :)

Comment: No worries -- If someone had to give me one dollar every time I missed something obvious, well... my adviser would be quite poor.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x} +x^{k+1}= \frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x} + \frac{1-x}{1-x}x^{k+1} = \frac{1-x^{k+1} + (1-x)x^{k+1}}{1-x} = \dots$$