# prove that $1+x+x^2+...x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} $

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Prove that $1+x+x^2+...x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} $

and how to prove this implies that for $|x|<1$

$$1+x+x^2+........=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

for the first part we can prove by induction but to get second one by using first one

Comment: Take limit $n \to \infty$ in your first part to get the answer to your second part.

Comment: For the first part, you can use induction.  You should include your attempt at the proof.

Comment: You can have a look at [Prove that $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^n=(1-a^{n+1})/(1-a)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563535) or [Proof of the formula $1+x+x^2+x^3+ \cdots +x^n =\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11703) and [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/11703).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

(Both for the induction part and for the limit).

Rewrite the r.h.s. as $\;\dfrac1{1-x}-\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.