# summation of $3^k$

Tags: closed-form, geometric-series, geometric-progressions

how do you write the closed form of a sum of the geometric progression of 3^n? Our teacher told us that $2^0+2^1.... 2^n$ is equal to $2^{n+1}-1$ but I am not sure how to apply that to a similar  scenario where $3^0+3^1.... 3^n$. I tried $3^{n+1}-1$ but that is not correct. What is the correct way to figure it?

Edit: I know that the summation is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^k$$ I am looking for a closed form solution.

Comment: In general, $1+x+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. So, for $x=3$, you have $1+3+...+3^n=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n+1}-1)$.

Comment: How about $\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1}?$

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. To me, it is clear that OP is not that advanced in maths, probably in secondary school, so why not take the chance to teach them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Values of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^N x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/values-of-sum-n-0-infty-xn-and-sum-n-0n-xn)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563535/42969

Answer (score 1):

Though the other answers are correct, I figured that if you only know about the sum $1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{n - 1}$, it is probably the best to write more details and avoid symbols whenever possible. Here is a proof that you can take a look at. Let's denote your sum as $S = 1 + 3 + 3^2 + \cdots + 3^{n - 1}$. Then you want to find $S$ (duh). Now since it is a geometric series, if you multiply $S$ by $3$, you will get

$$
3S = 3 \times 1 + 3 \times 3 + 3 \times 3^2 + \cdots + 3 \times 3^{n - 1} = 3 + 3^2 + 3^3 + \cdots + 3^n
$$

It might not be obvious how this is useful. However, let's compare $3S$ and the original series $S$ as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
&    &3S &= & & &3 &+ &3^2 &+ &3^3 &+ &\cdots &+ &3^{n - 1} &+ &3^n \\
&-    &S &= &1 &+ &3 &+ &3^2 &+ &3^3 &+ &\cdots &+ &3^{n - 1} \\
  \hline \\
&    &2S &= &-1 &&&&&&&&&&&+ &3^n
\end{array}
$$

Where the middle terms all cancel out because you are subtracting! Looking at the last row, we simply get

$$
2S = 3^n - 1
$$

Which of course means that

$$
S = \frac{3^n - 1}{2}
$$

As other suggested. I highly encourage you to copy this proof but replacing $3$ with $5$, or if you are comfortable enough, to replace $3$ by $x$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we have
$$1+x+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

You can prove it by Induction as follows-
$$1+x+...+x^n+x^{n+1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}+x^{n+1}=\frac{1-x^{n+2}}{1-x}$$

On second thought, since you have asked *the correct way to figure it*, one should probably exhibit that the terms cancel out and you get
$$(1+x+...+x^n)(1-x)=1-x^{n+1}$$

Comment: $3^4-1$ is 80 when it should be 40 unless my math is wrong. Can you explain why?

Comment: @tantan69 You are forgetting to divide by $3 - 1$ somewhere. If you just look at the last line, it says $(1 + 3 + \cdots + 3^n)(1 - 3) = (1 - 3^{n - 1})$