# Solving sum of $(-1)^n (1/2)^n$

Tags: summation

How to solve the following sum?

$$\sum_{n=0}^k (-1)^n (1/2)^n$$

Comment: It's a geometric series. Do the usual thing.

Comment: What about $\sum_{n=0}^k (-1)^n x^n=\sum_{n=0}^k (-x)^n$ first ?

Comment: That's a rather classical problem. What have you tried?

Comment: We have $(-1)^n (1/2)^n = (-1/2)^n$.

Comment: Hint: What is the $n$-th term for a geometric sequence.

Comment: @Aleksandar Sorry but I fail to get your hint.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/proof-of-the-formula-1xx2x3-cdots-xn-fracxn1-1x-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the geometric serie for $|x|<1$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{k }x^n=1+x+x^2+x^3+....=\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$$

then use $x=-1/2$

Comment: The OP wants the partial sum rather than the infinite series.

Comment: The OP wants the partial sum rather than an infinite series. The infinite series is easy to obtain.

Comment: @Aleksandar thanks

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Using [Exponent Combination Law](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Product) $a^mb^m=(ab)^m$ for real $a>0,b>0,m$

$\displaystyle\left(\dfrac12\right)^n=\left(-\dfrac12\right)^n$
$\displaystyle\implies\sum_{n=0}^k (-1)^n \left(\dfrac12\right)^n =\sum_{n=0}^k\left(-\dfrac12\right)^n$

which is a Geometric Series with common ratio $=-\dfrac12$

Comment: Should I keep going with $\frac{1-(-1/2)^{k+1}}{1-(-1/2)}$ ?

Comment: @andrepcg, Follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

Answer (score 0):

We have,

$s_{n}=\sum_{k=0} ^n (-\frac{1}{2})^n$

$s_0=1$

$s_1=\frac{1}{2}$

$s_2=\frac{3}{4}$

$s_3=\frac{5}{8}$

$s_4=\frac{11}{16}$

$s_5=\frac{21}{32}$

$s_{6}=\frac{43}{64}$

We can see the numerator is part of the Jacobsthal sequence.

We can later conclude,

$s_{n}=\frac{1}{3} [(-\frac{1}{2})^n +2]$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try $s_4$. "Clearly"...

Comment: Now you should compare 3 times the numerators to powers of 2...