# Proving a Complex Equality with Powers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that the following identity is valid for all $z$ with $z\neq1$:

$$1+z+z^2+...+z^n=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$

Comment: This is a standard fact about geometric series that is proved in hundreds of books, the wikipedia article about geometric series, and on this very site many times. Have you done any research about this problem?

Comment: Yes, I have. I was just curious on how to go about it. So, would standard Mathematical Induction be all? It seems too simple for me. I can post my solution shortly!

Comment: Yes, that is one of a *very* large number of ways to prove it. (And had you included that in your original question, it probably wouldn't have immediately been downvoted)

Comment: The result is immediate by synthetic division.

Comment: Key words : sum finite geometric series

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/proof-of-the-formula-1xx2x3-cdots-xn-fracxn1-1x-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
S=1+&z+z^2+z^3+\cdots+z^n\\
zS=\quad\quad&z+z^2+z^3+\cdots+z^n+z^{n+1}\\
\\
S-zS=1-z^{n+1}\\
S=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}
\end{align}

Comment: Note that a far more explained version of this same answer is given in the top-voted answer of the [faq version of this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn).

Answer (score 0):

Multiply out $(1-z)(1+z+z^2+\dots+z^n)$.

You get $(1+z+z^2+\dots+z^n)-(z+z^2+z^3+\dots+z^{n+1})=1-z^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**By induction**:

With $n=0$,
$$1=\frac{1-z^1}{1-z}.$$

Then

$$S_n+z^{n+1}=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}+z^{n+1}=\frac{1-z^{n+2}}{1-z}=S_{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$S_{n+1}=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}=\frac{1-z+z-z^{n+1}}{1-z}=1+zS_{n},$$ with $S_0=1$.

Then the iterates are

$$S_0=1,S_1=1+z,S_2=1+z+z^2,S_3=1+z+z^2+z^3,\cdots$$