# Polynomials and power series. How to prove $\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation, geometric-progressions

How do I prove that $$\dfrac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{10} $$

Attempt: By observing first  let assume that $∣x∣<1$ then $\dfrac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}=\dfrac{1}{1-x}(1-x^{11})=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots +x^n +\cdots)(1-x^{11})$

Any idea or hint?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series

Comment: The easiest way is to approve that $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{10})$ is equal to $1-x^{11}$ by just calculating the product. Nearly all terms will cancel out. Then, the equation must hold for $x\ne 1$

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: the equation $$\dfrac{1}{1-x}(1-x^{11})=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots +x^n +\cdots)(1-x^{11})$$ is not true for $|x|> 1$ so it is better to just make the direct product of $1-x$ and $1+x+\ldots+x^{10}$ as @Peter suggested in the second commentary, noticing that $\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}$ is just defined for $x\neq 1$.

Comment: This is a special case of [Proof of the formula $1+x+x^2+x^3+ \cdots +x^n =\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11703). (Perhaps they are close enough to be considered duplicates?)

Comment: hint: $1-x^{11}= 1+x-x+x^2-x^2+x^3-x^3+x^4-x^4+x^5-x^5+x^6-x^6+x^7-x^7+x^8-x^8+x^9-x^9+x^{10}-x^{10}-x^{11}$