# Proving $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In Spivak's *Calculus 3rd Edition*, there is an exercise to prove the following:

$$x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$$

I can't seem to get the answer. Either I've gone wrong somewhere, I'm overlooking something, or both. Here's my (non) proof:

$$\begin{align*}
x^n - y^n &= (x - y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y +\cdots+ xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}) \\
          &= x \cdot x^{n-1} + x \cdot x^{n-2} \cdot y + \cdots + x \cdot x \cdot y^{n-2} + x \cdot y^{n-1}\\
&\qquad + (-y) \cdot x^{n-1} + (-y) \cdot x^{n-2} \cdot y + \cdots + (-y) \cdot x \cdot y^{n-2} + (-y) \cdot y^{n-1}\\
          &= x^n + x^{n-1} y + \cdots + x^2 y^{n-2} + x y^{n-1} - x^{n-1}y - y^2 x^{n-2}  - \cdots- x y^{n-1} - y^n \\
          &= x^n + x^2 y^{n-2} - x^{n-2} y^2 - y^n  \\
          &\neq x^n - y^n
\end{align*}$$

Is there something I can do with $x^n + x^2 y^{n-2} - x^{n-2} y^2 - y^n$ that I'm not seeing, or did I make a mistake early on?

EDIT:

I should have pointed out that this exercise is meant to be done using nine of the twelve basic properties of numbers that Spivak outlines in his book:

- Associate law for addition
- Existence of an additive identity
- Existence of additive inverses
- Commutative law for additions
- Associative law for multiplication
- Existence of a multiplicative identity
- Existence of multiplicative inverses
- Commutative law for multiplication
- Distibutive law

Comment: Write out your expanded expression in two rows multiplying first by $x$ to get the first row and then by $-y$ to get the second row. If you write the second row so that expressions with the same power of $x$ are underneath each other, and do an extra term or two at the beginning and the end, you should detect quite easily what has gone wrong.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Be carefull the ... from the first and second part are not the same thing ;) So you cannot cancel ... by ....

Comment: Alternatively, you can use induction by writing $x^n-y^n = x(x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}) + (x-y)y^{n-1}$.

Comment: Another possibility is to write $x^n-y^n = x^n\left(1-\left(y/x\right)^n\right)$ (the case $x=0$ is trivial) and then use the geometric sum formula.

Comment: See the question [Algebraic Identity $a^{n}-b^{n} = (a-b) \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k}b^{n-1-k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11618/752). You can apply [Ruffini's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini's_rule). 
I have applied it in [my anwer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11684/752).

Comment: Use synthetic divison

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have everything right except the last line.

Maybe it is easier to do in this order:

$$(x−y)\left(x^{n−1}+x^{n−2}y+\cdots+xy^{n−2}+y^{n−1}\right)=\\
=x\cdot x^{n-1}-y\cdot x^{n-1} +x\cdot x^{n−2}y-
y\cdot x^{n−2}y+x\cdot x^{n−3}y^2-\cdots\\  \cdots -y\cdot x^2y^{n-3} +x\cdot xy^{n-2}-y \cdot y^{n-1}$$

The second term $y\cdot x^{n-1}$ is the same as the third term $x\cdot x^{n−2}y$  except the sign, similarly the 4th and the 5th terms are canceled... So the only terms left are: $x\cdot x^{n-1}$ and $y\cdot y^{n-1}$.

Comment: This leaves me in the exact same position that I'm in now ..

Comment: In your opening post, you (mistakenly) had two terms in addition to the ones grozhd points out are left

Comment: This could have been better explained, although I see what you did now. You added an extra term before the $...$ and multiplied it by $x$. Then you added another term after the $...$ and multiplied it by $(-y)$.

Thanks!

Comment: ohhhh I see why you started with $-y*x^2y^n-3$ after the ellipsis and not the $x*x^2y^n-3$... it's because $$-y*x^2y^n-3$$ cancels with the 2nd to last term because they are =

Answer (score 20):

I think it would be easier for you to recall

$$\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)(x-1) = x^n-1$$

and put $x=\dfrac{b}{a}$

$$\eqalign{
  & \left( {1 + \frac{b}{a} + \frac{{{b^2}}}{{{a^2}}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{{b^{n - 1}}}}{{{a^{n - 1}}}}} \right)\left( {\frac{b}{a} - 1} \right) = \frac{{{b^n}}}{{{a^n}}} - 1  \cr 
  & \left( {1 + \frac{b}{a} + \frac{{{b^2}}}{{{a^2}}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{{b^{n - 1}}}}{{{a^{n - 1}}}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{b - a}}{a}} \right) = \frac{{{b^n} - {a^n}}}{{{a^n}}}  \cr 
  & {a^{n - 1}}\left( {1 + \frac{b}{a} + \frac{{{b^2}}}{{{a^2}}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{{b^{n - 1}}}}{{{a^{n - 1}}}}} \right)\left( {b - a} \right) = {b^n} - {a^n}  \cr 
  & \left( {{a^{n - 1}} + b{a^{n - 2}} + {b^2}{a^{n - 3}} +  \cdots  + {b^{n - 1}}} \right)\left( {b - a} \right) = {b^n} - {a^n} \cr} $$

A little bit "tidier", so that we know what happens in between the dots...

$$\eqalign{
  & {x^n} - 1 = \left( {x - 1} \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{x^k}}   \cr 
  & \frac{{{b^n}}}{{{a^n}}} - 1 = \left( {\frac{b}{a} - 1} \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{{b^k}}}{{{a^k}}}}   \cr 
  & \frac{{{b^n} - {a^n}}}{{{a^n}}} = \left( {\frac{{b - a}}{a}} \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{{b^k}}}{{{a^k}}}}   \cr 
  & {b^n} - {a^n} = \left( {b - a} \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{b^k}{a^{n - k - 1}}}  \cr} $$

Answer (score 17):

Here is the inductive step, presented more conceptually

$$\rm\frac{x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}}{x-y}\: =\ x^n\: +\ y\ \frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$$

So, *intuitively,* proceeding inductively yields

$$\rm\:x^n + y\: (x^{n-1} + y\: (x^{n-2} +\:\cdots\:))\ =\ x^n + y\: x^{n-1} + y^2\: x^{n-2} + \:\cdots $$

Use this intuition to compose a *formal* proof by induction.

Comment: It should be possible to prove this using the basic properties of numbers discussed in Spivak's book: Associative law for addition, Existence of an additive identify, Existence of additive inverses, Commutative law for addition, Associative law for multiplication, Existence of a multiplicative identity, Existence of multiplicative inverses, Commutative law for multiplication, and Distributive law.

Answer (score 7):

Your method is sound, you just made a sort of arithmetic mistake. When cancelling or otherwise combining two sequences, try explicitly lining things up to make sure you do it right:

$$  \begin{align} x^n &+& x^{n-1} y &+& x^{n-2} y^2 &+& \cdots + x y^{n-1} &
\\ &-& x^{n-1} y &-& x^{n-2} y^2 &+& \cdots - x y^{n-1} &+&  y^n
\end{align}
$$

I've found that, when  shorthand starts becoming awkward and/or error prone, that it really is helpful to switch to summation notation. So, you are trying to prove

$$ x^n - y^n = (x-y) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-1-k} $$

and the first stem of your work would be

$$ \cdots = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k+1} y^{n-1-k} \right)
- \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} y^{n-k} \right)$$

and now, we can change the index to line things up: I'm substituting k = j-1:

$$ \cdots = \left( \sum_{(j-1)=0}^{n-1} x^{(j-1)+1} y^{n-1-(j-1)} \right)
- \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} y^{n-k} \right)$$
and simplifying

$$ \cdots = \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} x^{j} y^{n-j} \right)
- \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} y^{n-k} \right)$$

and now replacing $j$ with $k$.

$$ \cdots = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{k} y^{n-k} \right)
- \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} y^{n-k} \right)$$

(can you take it from here?)

Comment: I don't follow, can you explain?

Answer (score 5):

The $x^2 y^{n-2}$ term from $x \cdot x y^{n-2}$ is cancelled by the term from $(-y) \cdot 
x^2 y^{n-3}$.  Similarly, the $(-y) \cdot x^{n-2} y$ is cancelled by the $x \cdot x^{n-3} y^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Since powers of x and y is always greater than or equal to zero, You can prove it by mathematical induction.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I don't speak English well but I will try to write as correctly as possible.

Your demonstration is correct, but your idea of cancellation is incorrect.

$x^n−y^n=(x−y)(x^\left(n−1\right)+x^\left(n−2\right)y+⋯+xy^\left(n−2\right)+y^\left(n−1\right))$

When we multiply first for 'x' to our terms of the second parenthesis let's notice that all terms that contains 'x' go up one grade, this by exponent laws.
When we multiplies for 'y' to our terms of the second parenthesis let's notice that all terms that contains y go up one grade but the terms that contains x remain the same.
Therefore at the moment to cancel our terms, "ellipsis" of the formula cancel the terms left over in your demostration.

This is your result  $x^n+x^2y^\left(n−2\right)−x^\left(n−2\right)y^2−y^n$ the extra term $+x^2y^\left(n−2\right)$is "cancel" by the "ellipsis" because the term that is not visible but is in the "ellipsis" in the second parenthesis is
$(x^\left(n−1\right)+x^\left(n−2\right)y+⋯ (x^2y^\left(n-3\right)) ⋯+xy^\left(n−2\right)+y^\left(n−1\right)$ because on the left one degree goes up the 'x' and one degree goes down the y and cancel your term. Analogously the other extra term $-x^\left(n−2\right)y^2$ is cancel by the other "ellipsis" that came out of the first multiplication by x.

$x^n−y^n=(x−y)(x^\left(n−1\right)+x^\left(n−2\right)y+⋯+xy^\left(n−2\right)+y^\left(n−1\right))$

Dem.

By distributive law we have

$x(x^\left(n-1\right)+x^\left(n-2\right)y+...+xy^\left(n-2\right)+y^\left(n-1\right))$

$-y(x^\left(n-1\right)+x^\left(n-2\right)y+...+xy^\left(n-2\right)+y^\left(n-1\right))$   from where

---

$\quad x^n+x^\left(n-1\right)y+.........+x^2y^\left(n-2\right)+xy^\left(n-1\right)$

$\qquad -(x^\left(n-1\right)y+x^\left(n-2\right)y^2+.........+xy^\left(n-1\right)+y^n)$ therefore

$x^n-y^n$

Comment: Thank you. I also had the idea of cancellation. Thank you for explaining that the ellipsis has it's own rules

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + \dots + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1}$ is a geometric series with $n$ terms and a common factor of $y/x$, it equals
$$
\frac{x^{n-1}\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^n\right)}{1-\frac{y}{x}}=\frac{x^{n}\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^n\right)}{x-y}=\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y} \, ;
$$
multiplying through by $(x-y)$ gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Induction Hypothesis

Let n =k
Then ,
x^k -y^k = (x-y)(x^(k-1) +x^(k-2) y ....+y^k-1)
Let n= (k-1)
Then by Induction Hypothesis,
(x-y){x(x^(k-1) +x^(k-2) y) +y^k }
=» (x-y)(x^k +x^(k-1) y ... +y^k

Hence the formula is true for k+1 whenever true for k .
Therefore by Principle of Induction The formula is true for Positive Integers n≥2 .

Reference = Challenges and Thrills of Pre College Mathematics .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).