# GCD of exponents

Tags: exponentiation, gcd-and-lcm

I have been trying to determine a shorter method for calculating $\gcd(a^n + b^n, |a-b|).$ I noticed that, if I were to calculate (using the above formula) say $a = 100$ and $b = 4,$ starting from $1$ and ending at $n$ (a loop), at a certain point, the answer becomes constant. For $a = 100, b = 4, n = 100,$ I create a loop from $1$ to $n,$ and at each point, I apply the formula, the first answer $(n = 1)$ is $8,$ thereafter it is $32$ till when $n$ becomes $100.$ For optimization, I break out of the loop once two equal consecutive numbers are found and the latest number ($32$ here), becomes the answer. Does anyone know a straightforward formula for calculating $\gcd(a^n + b^n, a-b),$ or better still, my primary concern, a global formula for finding $a^n + b^n$

Note: 1<=a,b,n<=10^12

My Python Code for the above explanation follows suite

```
from functools import reduce
from fractions import gcd

a, b, n = map(int, raw_input().split()); ans = -1

if a == b:
    ans = (a**n) + (b**n)#a-b will give 0 and gcd(x,0) == x

else:
    for j in xrange(n):
        x = gcd((a**n)+(b**n),abs(a-b))

        if x != ans:
            ans = x
        else:
            break
print ans
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you mean by "a global formula for $a^n+b^n?$"  Why isn't $a^n+b^n$ a "global formula?"

Comment: If you are using python, you won't be able to beat the built-in methods of integer arithmetic in source code.  Have a look [here](https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/) for starters.

Comment: "What do you mean by "a global formula for an+bn?" Why isn't an+bn a "global formula?" Take for example, a^n - b^n can be sipmlified as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406703/how-to-simplify-an-bn do u know anything for a^n + b^n??

Comment: Since, for large $n$ and $a,b>1$, the smaller term will be $|a-b|$ a faster approach would be to observe that the *gcd* must be a factor of $|a-b|$.  So find those factors, order them in descending order, and see if they evenly divide $a^n+b^n$.  The first one that does is the *gcd*.

Comment: @postmortes true, but it takes more than ten seconds to compute a^n where a = 1000000 and n = 1000000. Talk less of computing b^n again before summing them up.

Comment: Knowing the size of $n$ you're interested in is pretty relevant :)  Thanks for editing it into your question :)