# How to prove $a^n − b^n = (a − b) \sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{n-i} b^{i-1}\le (a − b)na^{n−1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

Please tell if the problem can be solved using telescoping technique or not.

If yes, how to prove $a^n − b^n = (a − b) \sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{n-i} b^{i-1}\le (a − b)na^{n−1}$ using that. It is given that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}{+},\, a\gt b,\, n \in \mathbb{N}.$

I tried as follows, but was unsuccessful to pursue:

$a^n − b^n = a^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a^ib^{n-i}-a^ib^{n-i})-b^n=a^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-i}-b^n$

---

*Edit :* based on the selected answer's comment.

Writing a few terms of the series, $\sum_{i=1}^n (a^{n+1-i}b^{i-1}-a^{n-i}b^i)$ get:

For $n =5$, get the terms as:
$i=1, \,\, a^{5+1-1}b^{1-1}-a^{5-1}b^1 = a^5-a^4b.$
$i=2, \,\, a^{5-1}b^{2-1}-a^{5-2}b^2 = a^4b-a^3b^2.$
$i=3, \,\, a^{5-2}b^{3-1}-a^{5-3}b^3 = a^3b^2-a^2b^3.$
$i=4, \,\, a^{5-3}b^{4-1}-a^{5-4}b^4 = a^2b^3-a^1b^4.$
$i=5, \,\, a^{5-4}b^{3-1}-a^{5-3}b^5 = a^1b^4-b^5.$

Adding all the terms, get:

$a^5-a^4b+ a^4b-a^3b^2+a^3b^2-a^2b^3+a^2b^3-a^1b^4+a^1b^4-b^5 = a^5 - b^5$

Comment: Can you simply assume $a>b$?

Comment: @rtybase Thanks for reminding. It is a condition. But, how it helps is not clear.

Comment: Then, you are done, right? $b^{i-1}< a^{i-1}$ ...

Comment: @rtybase But, the first part is not solved still. I mean the unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: You can find some proofs of the equality here: [How to simplify $a^n - b^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406703/how-to-simplify-an-bn)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth the response by Mawhrin-skel feels the best as details the easier approach without resort to induction. I request something extra: is there any analytical significance of the formula.It is a novice's question, but some response or discussion will help a lot. Also, it seems like telescoping technique will not work here, as the second answer (there) by Tony Stark shows a binomial expansion, so the inside terms do not cancel out each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(a-b)\sum_{i=1}^n (a^{n-i}b^{i-1}) &=\sum_{i=1}^n (a^{n+1-i}b^{i-1}-a^{n-i}b^i )\\
&=a^n+\sum_{i=2}^n a^{n+1-i}b^{i-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^{n-i}b^i - b^n \\
&= a^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^{n-i}b^i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^{n-i}b^i-b^n\\
&=a^n-b^n
\end{align}

You might like to read the working backward to  be similar to what you attempted.

$b<a$, then

$$b^{i-1}\le a^{i-1}$$

$$a^{n-i}b^{i-1}\le a^{n-1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^na^{n-i}b^{i-1}\le \sum_{i=1}^na^{n-1}=na^{n-1}$$

Comment: You have seemingly used the telescoping approach. Please comment on my last comment to post to @MinusOne-Twelfth, for impossibility of using the telescoping approach, as the binomial approach shows an expansion. I mean the answer at : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/409071/424260.

Comment: Write out a few terms and verify if it is a telescoping sum.  A question can be approached from various angles sometimes, it doesn't mean that if an approach works, the other approach doesn't.

Comment: So, the binomial expansion is just a dumber way to prove the same. I mean that  the binomial expansion will not show the cancelling terms, so not a correct way or as detailed way as the telescoping approach. So, is the telescoping approach a finer one. Also, any possible analytical significance of the formula proved in the first part will guide me a lot to search for 'real' significance of the formula, which goes beyond even the telescoping approach.

Comment: no comments about intelligence of various methods.

Comment: Please tell something about the 'real' or analytical significance of the formula in question. I mean if could grasp more than derivation that concerns the behavior of the formula in real plane. Also, find my edit for showing the telescoping nature of the derivation by first few terms.

Comment: Please see my new post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3264938/424260. It concerns with a completeness (real analysis) based proof of existence of irrational roots of $\sqrt{2}$. It has attracted no comment (connected to solve the problem(s) posed) even after around 30 minutes, and having suitable tags to attract attention. It is mostly concerned with inequalities, and how change of sign turns $\lt$ to $\le$.

Comment: Please post something for my last post, as feel something is lacking in selected answer, but cannot tell clearly enough. It might be the comment by @HennoBrandsma is pointing to invalid use of IVT in the selected answer, but not explains his point clearly. It might be that there is something still lacking in there.

Answer (score 2):

For the equalty,

**By telescoping:** We have,

$$(a-b)\sum_{i=1}^na^{n-i}b^{i-1}=a\sum_{i=1}^na^{n-i}b^{i-1}-b\sum_{i=1}^na^{n-i}b^{i-1},$$
which can be rewritten
$$\sum_{i=1}^na^{n+1-i}b^{i-1}-\sum_{i=1}^na^{n-i}b^i=a^n+\sum_{i=2}^na^{n+1-i}b^{i-1}-b^n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^{n-i}b^i,$$
which on simplifying gives
$$a^n-b^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^{n-i}b^i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^{n-i}b^i=a^n-b^n.$$
**By induction:** You wish to prove
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{i=1}^n a^{n-i}b^{i-1}.$$
Let's try induction. For the $n=1$ case we have

$$(a-b)a^0b^0=a^1-b^1,$$
so the base case holds.

Now suppose the general case is true and consider the $n+1$ case. We have

$$(a-b)\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a^{n+1-i}b^{i-1}=(a-b)\sum_{i=1}^n a^{n+1-i}b^{i-1}+(a-b)a^0b^n,$$

which can be rewritten
$$a(a^n-b^n)+(a-b)b^n=a^{n+1}-ab^n+ab^n-b^{n+1}=a^{n+1}-b^{n+1},$$
so in fact the general case holds.

---

For the inequality, you can use induction too:

$$a^n-b^n\leq (a-b)na^{n-1}.\tag{*}$$
The base case clearly holds since $a^1-b^1\leq (a-b)a^0$. Now suppose (*) holds and consider the $n+1$ case,

$$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=a^na-b^nb=(a^n-b^n)(a+b)-a^nb+b^na\tag{1}$$

But since $a>b$, then

$$(1)\leq (a^n-b^n)(a+b)-a^nb+a^nb=(a^n-b^n)(a+b)-b(a^n-b^n),$$
which we can write
$$(a^n-b^n)a\leq a(a-b)na^{n-1}=(a-b)na^n\leq(a-b)(n+1)a^n,$$
as required.

---

Comment: I request that the derivation be in a constructive manner, not by induction. Also, if possible the analytical significance of the same be at least hinted at.

Comment: Sorry I misread, I thought "... using telescoping technique **or not**." referred to any method. I have also worked out the inequality proof too.

Answer (score 1):

**Geometric progression**
\begin{align}
(a-b)\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{n-i}b^{i-1}&=(a-b)a^{n-1}\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n}{1-\frac{b}{a}}\right)\\
&=a^n-b^n.
\end{align}
 Can you complete the answer now?

Comment: An extra question : is there any analytical significance of the formula derived / proved using induction.

Comment: Look at method 2. That's much simpler, it's a GP!

Comment: Please retain your induction based answer part.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\sum_{i=1}^na^{n-i}b^{i-1}=\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$$ if $$a\ne b$$

Comment: Please tell how to derive the formula. Or reference source, or googling name.

Comment: One way is to use induction!

Comment: Request a better way. I mean more rigorous. Say, (just a novice's guess) it might use analysis.

Comment: please respond. a negative response to my query of possibility of a rigorous proof will also help.

Comment: See the answers above!

Comment: The question is how to *prove* that $a^n − b^n = (a − b) \sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{n-i} b^{i-1}$, and your hint is that $\sum_{i=1}^na^{n-i}b^{i-1}=\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$ ?

Comment: Yes, this my hint.Do you have a better one?

Comment: The other one uses a geometric progression, is this better?

Comment: @MartinR His answer is complemented by his first comment. Issue is had to ask for that.