# Factorising Complex Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

Factorising complex numbers how did he get from ....(1) to ....(2) how did he get factorisation $z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1$ from trig factorsiation

[image]

Comment: Statement (2) is does not follow from anything preceding: it’s an algebraic identity. Here in the States, it’s usually taught in the high-schools.

Comment: See :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712758/derivation-of-factorization-of-an-bn

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x