# On re-writing polynomials of the form, $P(x) = x^n - b^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is a follow up question to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712769/409312), in which it says:

> Let $b$ be fixed, and consider the polynomial $P(x) = x^n - b^n$. Then there is a polynomial $Q(x)$, and a constant $r$, such that
>
> $P(x) = (x - b)Q(x) + r$

Could someone please tell me why this is true (without using the factorization formula for $a^n - b^n$ or the fact that $b$ is a root, since that's what the answer is *trying to prove*)? (Does it involve any theorems or facts from congruence-class arithmetic or am I just thinking too hard about this?)

Comment: [Euclidean division of polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division)

Comment: It is not assuming what it is trying to prove because of the $r$ term.  Once you allow $r$ this is a consequence of polynomial division.  The remainder is of lower degree than the polynomial you divide out.  Since we are dividing out a linear polynomial, the remainder is a constant.  The point of the proof is that $r=0$, so this is a factorization of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Polynomial remainder theorem:**
> If a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $x-a$, the remainder is $f(a)$.
> *Proof.*  Suppose $f(x)$ is divided by $x-a$.  Then we can write $$f(x)=(x-a)q(x)+r(x)$$ where $q(x)$ is the quotient and $r(x)$ is the remainder.  Since the remainder is at most one degree less than the divisor, we can conclude that $r(x)$ is a constant and rewrite the above as $$f(x)=(x-a)q(x)+R.$$
> By substitution $x=a$, we have $$f(a)=(a-a)q(a)+R\implies f(a)=R.$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Given polynomials $P(x)$ and $x-b$,

by [Euclidean division of polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division) there exist polynomials $Q(x)$ and $r(x)$

such that $P(x)=Q(x)(x-b)+r(x)$, where the degree of $r(x)$ is less than the degree of $x-b$.

Since $x-b$ is linear (first degree), $r(x)$ must be a constant.