# There exist $p(x)$, $k$ and $c$ such that $(x^n + a)(x^m + b)p(x) = x^k + c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

Given integers $a, b, n$, and $m$, how can I decide if there exist a polynomial $p(x)$ and integers $k$ and $c$ such that the following holds true over the integers?

$$(x^n + a)(x^m + b)p(x) = x^k + c$$

I noticed that for this to happen, we need a polynomial of the form $x^k + c$ that is divisible by both $x^n + a$ and $x^m + b$, but I don't know how to use necessary condition.

Maybe such polynomial $x^k + c$ exist only for very specific values of $a, b, n$, and $m$...

Comment: If $P(X)$ divides $Q(X)$, then $\text{roots}(P)\subseteq \text{roots}(Q)$. I guess that you can use this knowledge to find some conditions on $k$ and $c$, using the complex roots of the polynoms.

Comment: While this is not the answer, notice that p(x) exists because $p(x)=1$ is a candidate and $p(x)=x^k+c$ is also a candidate, so p(x) exists. On a more practical tone, you may have to examine the powers of the L.H.S in comparison to the R.H.S and try to see what you get when you equate coefficients.

Comment: @NoChance but if we set $p(x) = x^k + c$, then the equation never holds, and $p(x) = 1$ isn't a candidate neither, since it would imply $(x^n+a)(x^m+b) = x^k + c$, which is false in general.

Comment: @Marcellus, thanks for the clarification, it was a quick thought...

Answer (score 1):

As Florian mentions in a comment the roots of $(x^n + a)(x^m + b)$ must be contained in the roots of $(x^k + c)$.

The $N$th roots of any number $z \in \mathbb{C}$ lie equally spaced along a circle in the complex plane with radius $|\sqrt[N]{z}|$. Therefore, if the $n$th roots of $-a$ and the $m$th roots of $-b$ are also the $k$th roots of $-c$, they must all lie on the same circle with radius $r = |\sqrt[n]{-a}| = |\sqrt[m]{-b}| =  |\sqrt[k]{-c}| $. From which we can deduce $|a| = r^n, |b| = r^m$ and $|c| = r^k$.

Let's write $a,b,c$ as complex numbers, with $arg(a) = \alpha$, $arg(b) = \beta$ and $arg(c) = \gamma$ (Note that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \{0,\pi\}$. Then our equation becomes

\begin{eqnarray}
(x^n + r^n e^{i \alpha})(x^m + r^m e^{i \beta}) p(x)  &=& (x^k + r^k e^{i \gamma}) \nonumber \\
\iff (x^n - r^n e^{i (\alpha + \pi)})(x^m - r^m e^{i (\beta + \pi)}) p(x)  &=& (x^k - r^k e^{i (\gamma + \pi)}) \nonumber \\
\iff \left(x^n - \left[r e^{\frac{i (\alpha + \pi)}{n}}\right]^n \right) \left( x^m - \left[r e^{\frac{i (\beta + \pi)}{m}}\right]^m \right)  p(x)  &=& \left( x^k - \left[r e^{\frac{i (\gamma + \pi)}{k}}\right]^k \right) \nonumber \\
\end{eqnarray}

Next, we can apply the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330185)

$$
(x^N - y^N) = \prod_{j=0}^{N-1} \left( x - y e^{\frac{2 \pi i j}{N}} \right)
$$

to factor our equation as

\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{u=0}^{n-1} \left(x - r e^{ \frac{i (\alpha + \pi)}{n}} e^{\frac{2 \pi i u}{n}} \right)
\prod_{v=0}^{m-1} \left(x - r e^{ \frac{i (\beta + \pi)}{m}} e^{\frac{2 \pi i v}{m}} \right)
p(x)
&=&
\prod_{w=0}^{k-1} \left(x - r e^{ \frac{i (\gamma + \pi)}{k}} e^{\frac{2 \pi i w}{k}} \right)\nonumber \\
\iff \prod_{u=0}^{n-1} \left(x - r e^{ \frac{i (\alpha + \pi + 2 \pi u)}{n}} \right)
\prod_{v=0}^{m-1} \left(x - r e^{ \frac{i (\beta + \pi + 2 \pi v)}{m}} \right)
p(x)
&=&
\prod_{w=0}^{k-1} \left(x - r e^{ \frac{i (\gamma + \pi + 2 \pi w)}{k}} \right)\nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}

From this is should be clear that each of the linear factors on the LHS must be equal to exactly one of the linear factors on the RHS, and this can only be the case when $k$ is a multiple of both $m$ and $n$.

Further, note that the RHS of our equation has no repeated factors, so the same must be true on the LHS. A repeated factor occurs if for any value of $ u = 0, \dots n-1$ and $v \in \{ 0,\dots m-1\}$ we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
r e^{ \frac{i (\alpha + \pi + 2 \pi u)}{n}} &=&r e^{ \frac{i (\beta + \pi + 2 \pi v)}{m}}\nonumber \\
\iff \frac{i(\alpha +\pi + 2 \pi u)}{n} &\equiv& \frac{i(\beta +\pi + 2 \pi v)}{m} \text{ mod } 2 \pi \nonumber \\
\iff  \frac{\alpha + 2 \pi u}{n} &\equiv& \frac{\beta + 2 \pi v}{m} \text{ mod } 2 \pi \nonumber \\
\end{eqnarray}

As long as this equivalence is never satisfied (and $|\sqrt[n]{-a}| = |\sqrt[m]{-b}| =  |\sqrt[k]{-c}|$ and $m,n | k$), you can be certain that all the factors of $(x^n + a)$ and $(x^m + b)$ will appear precisely once as factors of $(x^n + c)$. Hence $p(x)$ will be a polynomial.... over $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

Comment: Thank you, it is very interesting! Do you think that it is sufficient to have $n|k$ and $m|k$ to show that the linear factors of RHS appear on the LHS, or is it really only a necessary condition?

Comment: No it is not sufficient. Consider  $(z^2 + 1)(z^2 -1) = (z^4 -1) \nmid (z^4 +1)$.

Comment: And it is very interesting! Although it's a bit of a cheat answer, the real challenge is to show when $ p(x) \in \mathbb{z}[X]$, although it might take some results from field theory or Galois theory.

Comment: Actually I think the example I just gave shows my answer is incomplete!