# How can I prove this equation holds?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

As the final part of a big proof I got for uni homework: (It is an extra question, may be unsolvable)

$$k^n<\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}ik^{n-i}(2^i-1)$$

My idea is to develop the right side into an $(x+y)^n$ type thing, but it is not in  a correct form for this.

This is said (by my homeworks) to be true for each $n > 2$, and $k \in N+$

How can I prove/develop this equation?

**Edit:**

- I tried induction, but failed to find a common expression.
- I tried simplifying into $(x+y)^n$ but failed doing that as well, because $(2^i-1)$ is not a $y^i$
- This started from $k^n < (k+2)^n - (k+1)^n$

Comment: if it works for n, does it follow it works for n+1?

Comment: There's a subtraction on the right hand side. Use that to write the entire sum as the difference between two sums. Are the two sums now in the "correct form" for what you want?

Comment: @shaihorowitz Tried induction, but failed getting a common expression, because of the combinatoric part (n choose i)

Comment: @DanPiponi That is a point before. k^n < (k+2)^n - (k+1)^n, which developed to this, which I don't know how to develop further.

Comment: As an aside, are there meant to be limits on what values of $k$ are allowed?  I notice that for $k=-1$ and $n$ even, one has $1<1$ which is not true.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh sorry, yes. k is N+

Comment: $$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom nik^{n-1}<\sum_{i=0}^n\binom nik^{n-1}(2i-1)$$

Comment: @SimpleArt As far as I know, $(x+y)^n$ requires $x > 0, y > 0$, therefore, this cannot be created

Comment: For the last line in your question, $12^3-11^3 = 397 \not> 10^3$, is the question correct?

Comment: This makes me question the supposed proof mentioned by the OP in "*it does work for n=3, that was simple to prove.*"  Considering that counterexamples exist for $n=3$, it should not have been possible to prove.  I would expect as well that it is false for larger $n$ as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm so dumb! looking at the proof I switched the sign (< to >).. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @Amit well, even that would be hard, since $5^3 = 125<127 = 7^3-6^3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement wishing to be proven is as mentioned equivalent to whether or not for $n>2$ and $k\in\Bbb N$ we have the following relation:

$$k^n < (k+2)^n - (k+1)^n$$

This is false.

Consider the validity of the statement for $k=6, n=3$.  One has $6^3=216$ and $(6+2)^3 - (6+1)^3 = 512 - 343 = 169$

$$6^3 = 216> 169 = (6+2)^3 - (6+1)^3$$

---

Why these are equivalent is because $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}k^{n-i}(2^i-1) = \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}k^{n-i}2^i\right) - \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}k^{n-i}\right) = (k+2)^n - (k+1)^n$

Comment: I wanted to  prove this so much, I did not even consider it is false. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

On the bright side 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}k^{n-i}\left ( 2^i-1 \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}k^{n-i}2^i - \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}k^{n-i}=(k+2)^n-(k+1)^n=$$$$(k+2 - (k+1))\cdot((k+2)^{n-1}+(k+2)^{n-2}(k+1)+...+(k+1)^{n-1})>$$$$(k+1)^{n-1}+(k+1)^{n-1}+..+(k+1)^{n-1}=n(k+1)^{n-1}$$

This is definitely true for $n>k$.

Comment: Can you please explain how you did every step? (just formula name, because I'm lost)

Comment: @Amit $x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\dots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$.  This is seen to be true via properties of telescoping series.  Try it for yourself to see further.  There is no "formula name" to my knowledge for this tidbit.  See for example, [this question and answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1).

Comment: Yep $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+...+a^2b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$ it's a well known identity.

Comment: @rtybase Thanks. I now understand what you did there