# Prove that $a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-1})$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, alternative-proof

### Exercise

> Prove that $a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-1})$.

---

I've posted my solution below. In case someone has a more clever solution, feel free to post it!

(TBH, I was surprised that there was no question on Math.SE regarding this equation!)

Comment: `I was surprised that there was no question on Math.SE regarding this equation` Maybe because that's simply the formula for the geometric progression sum $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1} = (1-x^n)/(1-x)$ with $x=b/a$  which is fairly well known.

Comment: Oh, that may explain it (but, I actually am not aware of that one).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n\geq1$,
\begin{align}
(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-1-i}&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{i+1}b^{n-1-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a^{i+1}b^{n-(i+1)}-a^ib^{n-i})\\
&=a^n-b^n&&(\text{telescoping sum})
\end{align}

Answer (score 8):

The result is essentially the fact that $1+x+ \cdots + x^{n-1} = {1-x^n \over 1-x}$ (for $x \neq 1$), or equivalently that
$(1-x)(1+x+ \cdots + x^{n-1}) = 1 -x ^n$ for any $x$.

If $a=b$, or $a=0$ then the result is true.

Suppose $a \neq 0$ and $a \neq b$. Then letting $x={b \over a}$ in the above
and multiplying the result by $a^n$ yields the desired result.

To see the above result, note that
$(1-x) (1+x+ \cdots + x^{n-1}) = (1+x+ \cdots + x^{n-1})-(x+x^2+ \cdots + x^{n}) = 1- x^n$.

Answer (score 4):

$a^n - b^n =$

$= a^{n}b^{0} + (a^{n-1}b^{1} + a^{n-2}b^{2} + \cdots + a^{2}b^{n-2} + a^{1}b^{n-1}) \\ \space\space\space - a^{0}b^{n} - (a^{n-1}b^{1} + a^{n-2}b^{2} + \cdots + a^{2}b^{n-2} + a^{1}b^{n-1}) = $

$= (a^{n}b^{0} + a^{n-1}b^{1} + a^{n-2}b^{2} + \cdots + a^{2}b^{n-2} + a^{1}b^{n-1}) \\ \space\space\space - (a^{n-1}b^{1} + a^{n-2}b^{2} + \cdots + a^{2}b^{n-2} + a^{1}b^{n-1} + a^{0}b^{n}) = $

$= a(a^{n-1}b^{0} + a^{n-2}b^{1} + \cdots + a^{1}b^{n-2} + a^{0}b^{n-1}) \\ \space\space\space - b(a^{n-1}b^{0} + a^{n-2}b^{1} + \cdots + a^{1}b^{n-2} + a^{0}b^{n-1}) = $

$= (a - b)(a^{n-1}b^{0} + a^{n-2}b^{1} + \cdots + a^{1}b^{n-2} + a^{0}b^{n-1})= $

$= (a - b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1})$

Comment: Looks good to me!