# Formula for expanding powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't seem to understand the following: 
$$A^n-B^n=\left(A-B\right)\cdot \left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\cdots+A\cdot B^{n-2}+B^{n-1}\right)$$

How can i derive this formula ? Also, when does the $A^\text{something}$ end and when does $B^\text{something}$ start.

Thank you.

Comment: multiply the right-hand side out

Comment: Hint. What does this equality say when $n=2$? The second factor on the right then has just two terms. Now look at $n=3$. The second factor will have three terms.

Comment: Note that the powers of A and B don't start or end - they are present in every term. We begin with $A^{n-1}\cdot B^0$, then the next term is found by dividing by A and multiplying by B (i.e. $A^{n-2}\cdot B^1$, $A^{n-3}\cdot B^2$, ...), until we reach $B^{n-1}$.

Comment: It might help to think carefully about the distributive property of multiplication over addition:  $(A-B) C = AB - AC$.  Let $C$ be the sum, then distribute both $A$ and $B$ across the sums (this requires *two* distribution steps).  You should see a pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031059/prove-that-an-bn-a-ban-1-an-2b-cdots-bn-1)  [Also related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712758/derivation-of-factorization-of-an-bn).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write it in sum notation and try to work out the brackets.
$$
\left(A-B\right)\cdot \left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\cdots+A\cdot B^{n-2}+B^{n-1}\right) = (A-B)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A^{n-i-1}B^{i} = \cdots
$$

Comment: For me at least,  "writing in sum notation" makes the problem harder, not easier. When I see sum notation I convert it to a form with dot-dot-dots. Perhaps best to just "work out the brackets" (that is, distribute) right from the start.

Comment: I find both useful when solving a problem, but the sum notation seems more formal and rigorous to me. Who is to say that the pattern in $A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\cdots$ does not continue as something like this: $A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+A^{n-4}\cdot B^2 + A^{n-8}\cdot B^3+\cdots+A^{n-2^k}\cdot B^k+\cdots$?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the computations:

> $$A\left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\cdots+A\cdot B^{n-2}+B^{n-1}\right)$$ $$=A^n+A^{n-1}B+A^{n-2}B^2+....+A^2B^{n-2}+AB^{n-1}$$

.

> $$B\left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\cdots+A\cdot B^{n-2}+B^{n-1}\right)$$ $$=BA^{n-1}B^2A^{n-2}+A^{n-3}B^3+....+B^n$$

If substract: 
$$A\left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\cdots+A\cdot B^{n-2}+B^{n-1}\right)-B\left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}\cdot B+\cdots+A\cdot B^{n-2}+B^{n-1}\right)=A^n-B^n$$

In other words,if you notice, everything will be canceled  out and the only thing remaining will be $A^n-B^n$

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$A^n-B^n=(A-B)(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+\cdots+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1}),$$
where:
$$S_n=A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+\cdots+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1}$$
is the sum of the first $n$ terms of geometric progression with the first term $A^{n-1}$ and the common ratio $\frac{B}{A}$, hence:
$$(A-B)\cdot S_n=(A-B)\cdot \frac{A^{n-1}\left(1-\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)^n\right)}{1-\frac{B}{A}}=A^n-B^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

> when does the $A^\text{something}$ end and when does $B^\text{something}$ start

$$
A^6 - B^6 = (A-B)(A^5 + A^4B + A^3B^2 + A^2B^3+AB^4+B^5)
$$
When $n=6$ then the powers of $A$ are $5,4,3,2,1,0$ in that order, and the powers of $B$ are $0,1,2,3,4,5$ in that order.