# Why does $x^n = \left[(x-1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k\right]+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-series

I was curious about the formula for the difference between a number powered by a certain number and the sum of the number powered from 0 to the number - 1. I found this formula but I'm not sure if this is correct, and if it was correct, I couldn't prove it in a "proper" way. Can someone here show me the proof of this formula because I'm really curious about it?

$$x^n = \left[(x-1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k\right]+1$$

Comment: You are asking why $99999+1 = 100000$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas

Comment: The sum $(x-1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(x^{k+1} - x^k)$ is a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). A lot of cancellations appear among the terms and you can read off the end result by replacing the $k$ in $x^{k+1}$ by the largest possible $k$ and the $k$ in $x^k$ by the smallest possible $k$. This gives you $(x-1)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k = x^{(n-1)+1} - x^0 = x^n - 1$. Look at above wiki entries for more examples of this sort of sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a finite series
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1}$$
We want to find a closed expression for $S$. Note that by multiplying by $x$, we get
$$Sx=x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n$$
Now subtract both eqations and note the massive cancellation,
$$(x-1)S=x^n-1$$
$$(x-1)S+1=x^n$$
$$\left[(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k\right]+1=x^n$$

Comment: Thanks, a really brief and clear explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the formula to factor a polynomial in the form of $a^n - b^n$ ?

$x^n - 1^n = x^n - 1 = (x-1)(\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:x^k1^{n-1-k}) = (x-1)(\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:x^k)$

You take the expression above and you add $+ 1$ to get $x^n$

Comment: Thanks, really helpful

Comment: @edward for proof of $a^n - b^n$ look up https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2031074/

Comment: thanks, its all clear to me now