# General factorization of $x^n-y^n$ (n is real)

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am looking for a general expansion of $x^{n}-y^{n}$ with $x,y>0$ and $n$ being real. I came across the following formula ([Proving $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1))

$$x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{(n-1)}+x^{(n-2)}y+...+y^n)$$

Does it hold true for $n \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I don't think there's a nice *general* factorization for $\;n\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: It's not even clear what a "factorization" would mean in a case like this.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a general formula or a very useful factorization, but, for example, $x^e-y^e = (x^{\sqrt{e}} - y^{\sqrt {e}})(x^{\sqrt {e}} + y^{\sqrt {e}})$

Comment: @Χpẘ That isn't correct - it is $x^e-y^e=(x^{e/2}-y^{e/2})(x^{e/2}+y^{e/2})$.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the correction.

Comment: @user1110341 How can this question be a duplicate of the one that you mentioned? This question is concerned about the case in which $n$ is an arbitrary real number, whereas the one that you mentioned is about $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

If you write $x = y + t$, then you can use the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) on $x^n = (y+t)^n$, so

$$\eqalign{ x^n - y^n &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty {n \choose k} y^{n-k} t^k\cr
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {n \choose k} y^{n-k} (x-y)^k\cr
&= (x-y) \sum_{k=1}^\infty {n \choose k} y^{n-k} (x-y)^{k-1}}  $$
The series converges for $|x-y| < |y|$.

Comment: @{Robert} does it hold true for $n<0$?

Comment: Yes, it works for $n < 0$, or for complex $n$ for that matter.

Comment: Thanks @{Robert}

Answer (score 0):

You could factor out $x - y$, giving you:

$$(x - y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + ... xy^{n - 2} + y^{n - 1}) = \\(x - y)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}~y^{n - 1 - i}$$

**Edit:** The question was changed to include this factorization after this answer was posted.

Comment: AmagicalFishy, how many terms will the summation contain when $n \in R$ (say $n = 0.8$)?