# Prove by mathematical induction: $x^n - y^n$ is divisible by $x - y$, for all positive integers $n$.

Tags: induction

Here is what I have so far:

Base: When $n=1$, we have $x^1 - y^1 = x - y$. Hence, P(1) is true.

Inductive hypothesis: We assume that P(k) is true: $x^k - y^k$ is divisible by  $x - y$. That is: $x^k-y^k=(x - y)z$, for some integer $z$

Inductive step: We show that P(k+1) is true. That is:

$x^{k+1} - y^{k+1} = (x - y)z$

I don't quite know where to go from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1)

Answer (score 7):

The induction hypothesis should be “$x-y$ divides $x^k-y^k$”, not that they're equal.

Hint: $x^{k+1}-y^{k+1}=x^{k+1}-xy^{k}+xy^k-y^{k+1}$

Alternate hint: from the induction hypothesis you have $x^k-y^k=(x-y)z$, so $y^k=x^k-(x-y)z$ and therefore
$$
x^{k+1}-y^{k+1}=x^{k+1}-x^ky+(x-y)yz
$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but where did z on the RHS come from?

Comment: $z$ is a polynomial defined by $z=\dfrac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$.

Comment: @Andy $z$ exists by the induction hypothesis that asserts divisibility. You need not know what it looks like, just that it exists.