# Positive integer solution such that $7^m - 3^m$ is prime

Tags: divisibility

Find all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, for which the expression $7^m - 3^m$ a prime. What would be the general strategy for solving this? I have no clue where to begin. I tried picking $m$ and checking some values but I don't see any relation between them. This question can be solved using modular arithmetic as well but im not sure how. What I do know is that $7^m - 3^m > 1$.

Comment: For a start, when $m$ is odd, $7^m-3^m$ is even.

Comment: Reduce mod $4$.

Comment: $7^m - 3^m$ is *always* even...

Comment: Use the Factor Theorem as in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

But $7^m - 3^m$ for positive $m$ is not only even but is a multiple of $4$ which is not prime [ETA as noted in comments already]. So definitely not prime.

In general, if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers satisfying $a-b = c$, then working mod $c$, one can see that $a^m-b^m$ is always a multiple of $c$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs

Answer (score 1):

We have $7^{m}-3^{m}$ and m is positive. So,
$$7^{m}-3^{m}=(7-3)(7^{m-1}+7^{m-2}.3+7^{m-3}.3^{2}+......7^{2}.3^{m-3}+7.3^{m-2}+3^{m-1})$$
$$7^{m}-3^{m}=\mathbf{4}.(7^{m-1}+7^{m-2}.3+7^{m-3}.3^{2}+......7^{2}.3^{m-3}+7.3^{m-2}+3^{m-1})$$
$$7^{m}-3^{m}=\mathbf{4}.g(m)$$
So 4 is a root of this for m ($m\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$) positive. So $7^{m}-3^{m}$ is not a prime.

Comment: where can i read more about the factorization you came up with? Im not sure how you split into that factorization. Is it just the regular factorization of $a^n - b^n$? Im just confused about the "." symbols used in the factorization

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ I just saw this in x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y) , x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+x.y+y^2) , x^4-y^4=(x-y)(x^3+x^2.y+x.y^2+y^3) format. Then I solved this like this.I learned this from my mathematics teacher in the past times. So if you need more information about this factorisation, just go to [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1).